# Integrated Windows Authentication Wininet

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wininet

Hi experts
I need to send an http request from C++ application using wininet API. 
User is behind ISA proxy server that is configured to use Integrated Windows Authentication. 
When I get error 407 (proxy authentication required) I use InternetErrorDlg to ask the user for credentials. This is not an ideal solution as the IE is able to use current user's credentials transparently. Is there a way to do this ?

Sample code for request

```
hRequest = HttpOpenRequest ( 
    hConnect, 
    "POST", 
    query.c_str(), 
    HTTP_VERSION, 
    NULL, 
    cAcceptTypes, 
    INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE| INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION,
    0);

bRet = HttpSendRequest(
                hRequest,
                NULL,
                0,
                (LPVOID)dataXml.c_str(),
                (DWORD)dataXml.length());

bRet = HttpQueryInfo(
                hRequest,
                HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER | HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,
                &dwStatus,
                &dwSize,
                NULL);


if (dwStatus == HTTP_STATUS_PROXY_AUTH_REQ)
{

    ProxyAuthenticate( hRequest );  // Here I call InternetErrorDlg
            bRet = HttpSendRequest(
                hRequest,
                NULL,
                0,
                (LPVOID)dataXml.c_str(),
                (DWORD)dataXml.length());
```

}

Comment: Can you show some sample code, WinInet would typically handle the authentication automatically using the local credentials unless you have explicitly disabled the authentication using InternetSetOption.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` to initialize Wininet in your process:

```
InternetOpen(clientName, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: hSession = InternetOpen ( "ddd",  INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, 0, 0 );